# Node.js mssql module transaction not working with async await

Tags: node.js, node-mssql

```
config = {
    user: process.env.PROD_USER,
    password: process.env.PROD_PASSWORD,
    server: process.env.PROD_SERVER,
    database: process.env.PROD_DATABASE,
    options: {
        abortTransactionOnError: true, // <-- SET XACT_ABORT ON
    },
}

const pool = await sql.connect(config);
const transaction = new sql.Transaction();
await transaction.begin();

const result = await this.get_sp_data(
    data[0],
    sp.InsertTransactionMaster,
    res
);

const masterId = result.recordset[0].MasterId || 0;

if (masterId) {
    asyncForeach(req.body.TransactionDetail, async (value) => {
        const detailData = {
            MasterId: masterId,
            SubServiceId: value.SubServiceId,
            Rate: value.Rate,
            Quantity: value.Quantity,
            Amount: value.Amount,
            CreatedBy: req.user.id || 0,
            MemberId: value.MemberId,
            SubMemberIddd: value.SubMemberId || null,
        };
        await this.get_sp_data(detailData, sp.InsertTransactionDetail, res);
    });
}

await transaction.commit();
console.dir('Transaction commited.');
```

My custom code is between begin and commit to execute a stored procedure to insert master data after inserting master data master id return that id I use to insert multiple detail data using for loop and last.

I have explicitly place erroneous code in detail insert but transaction is not rolling back as a result master data inserted and giving error of detail.

Comment: I think you need to pass the transaction around like in the docs: `const request = new sql.Request(transaction)`

Comment: can you please give example as i have try and put request sentence but not working

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/mssql#transaction Sry, idk myself.